# How can I find a path between two points quickly?

Tags: java, graph

I need to generate a path between two points in a manner with a good runtime. However, this path doesn't have to be the shortest, or even short; I just need a path that works. Are there any good algorithms that would do this?

Right now I'm using Dijkstra's algorithm to find the shortest path between two points. (I am required to use this algorithm). However, if I know the length of a path between the start and end, even if it isn't the shortest, it will be able to "kill" a lot of paths that aren't the shortest. So, I can get a path by generating every path, but I was hoping to avoid that to generate an upper cap.

Comment: Path between two points is called `line`...

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Bedla the OP is not asking about a line in a coordinate plane, he is asking about a path between nodes in a graph.

Comment: Presumably you could modify Dijkstra's to return the first path it finds.

Comment: @bhspencer See revisions, how this question looked like at the time of my comment and then you will understand why i wrote it.